# Using a str_replace within a php tag

Tags: str-replace

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong here. Quite a novice when it comes to PHP

Here is my code:

```
<?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; str_replace("<br />","");   ?>
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: The code brings up errors. I basically want to replace a <br /> with nothing

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct way of executing that is this.:

`echo str_replace("<br />", "", $breadcrumb['text']);`

In this case, you want to replace all br-tags with "" in the $breadcrumb['text'] variable.

Look at the documentation for that function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: This makes nothing appear for me

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. You should echo also. This function should return the `$breadcrumb['text']` variable but without all the br-tags. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, it's still not working for me here is my full code -

Comment: <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>">
      <?php if ($breadcrumb['text'] == $heading_title) { ?>
        <strong><?php echo str_replace("<br />", "", $breadcrumb['text']); ?></strong>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </a>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: It's very hard to read your code like this, I'm certain the function should work in your case. What exactly do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: I have added a photo up the top so you can see what I mean. Does that help?

Comment: Could it maybe be that the else statement in your code is being executed which does not contain the str_replace function ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand:

```
<?php
    $breadcrumb['text'] = "Something <br /> Next line but now on first <br />";
    str_replace("<br />","", $breadcrumb['text']);
    echo $bread;
?>
```